# where to release a __block variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have following code snippet:

```
-(void) doSomething
{
    __block NSMutableArray *objArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
      [self performOperationWithBlock:^(void)
      {
         //adding objects to objArray
         .
         .
         //operation with objArray finished

         // 1. should objArray be released here?
      }];

      //2. should objArray be released here?
}
```

Should I autorelease the objArray?

Comment: `__block` means that you don't want blocks to retain array, so version 2 is more logical. I would use `autorelease` on construction.

Comment: You don't need `__block` if you just want to add objects to the array in the block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's an asynchronous call, it would make sense to create the `NSMutableArray` inside the actual block:

```
  [self performOperationWithBlock:^(void)
  {
     NSMutableArray *objArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

     //adding objects to objArray
     .
     .
     //operation with objArray finished

     // 1. should objArray be released here?
  }];
```

As you won't be needing it after the block (it only makes sense for the duration of the async operation), so in the end release it after you have used it. Or, you can simply:

```
     NSMutableArray *objArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

And in this case you don't need to release it.

If it's a sync call, you should `release` it after the block.

---

**Note:** I am assuming you are populating the `NSMutableArray` before being used on the block, which means it makes sense to be created before the block starts.

**Async approach:**

```
-(void) doSomething
{
   // Remove the `__block` qualifier, you want the block to `retain` it so it
   // can live after the `doSomething` method is destroyed
    NSMutableArray *objArray = // created with something useful

    [self performOperationWithBlock:^(void)
     {
       // You do something with the objArray, like adding new stuff to it (you are modyfing it).
       // Since you have the __block qualifier (in non-ARC it has a different meaning, than in ARC)
       // Finally, you need to be a good citizen and release it.
     }];

    // By the the time reaches this point, the block might haven been, or not executed (it's an async call).
    // With this in mind, you cannot just release the array. So you release it inside the block
    // when the work is done
}
```

**Sync Approach**:

It assumes that you need the result immediately, and it makes sense when you do further work with the Array, after the block has been executed, so:

```
-(void) doSomething
{
   // Keep `__block` keyword, you don't want the block to `retain` as you
   // will release it after
    __block NSMutableArray *objArray = // created with something useful

    [self performOperationWithBlock:^(void)
     {
         // You do something with the objArray, like adding new stuff to it (you are modyfing it).
     }];
    // Since it's a sync call, when you reach this point, the block has been executed and you are sure
    // that at least you won't be doing anything else inside the block with Array, so it's safe to release it

    // Do something else with the array

    // Finally release it:

    [objArray release];
}
```

Comment: Lets say I need to populate this array outside of the block, then what will be the picture?

Comment: @devgr, is it async or sync the block call?

Comment: I need to understand with both the perspective Synch and Asynch.

Comment: @devgr pay attention to the `__block` keyword.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jacky Boy! I am having a little confusion whether __block variable and scope variable (i.e objArray) are copied or retained?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45492/discussion-between-jacky-boy-and-dev-gr)

Answer (score 1):

You should release it after the `performOperationWithBlock:` method has finished, in my opinion, provided that method is *synchronous* (i.e. works on the same thread as the calling thread).

If that method is *asynchronous* then it should be released within the block.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using ARC, you should release the array when you no longer need it. According to the comments you added and assuming the `doSomething` method doesn't do anything with the array outside of the block, it should be at your `1.` mark.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2. Release it after `[self performOperationWithBlock:...]`. Block will retain and release yours objArray by himself. Releasing inside block is dangerous: block can be performed twice and then objArray will be released twice, but it's should de released once. So there is only one option left: 2.

Comment: I am having little confusion whether __block variables are retained or copied.

Comment: @devgr, all objects got retained in block. copy have no sense and not all classes support copy. To bad you haven't marked right answer.

Comment: objects got retained only when you copy the block.